# MS-SQL how to add missing month in a table values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following entries,

| ID | date | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2012-04-30' | 5 |
| 1 | '2012-06-30' | 4 |
| 1 | '2012-07-31' | 25 |
| 2 | '2012-04-30' | 7 |
| 2 | '2012-05-31' | 4 |
| 2 | '2012-06-30' | 1 |
| 2 | '2012-07-31' | 6 |

I need to add missing month and the date which gets added should be the last date of that month with frequency value as 0.

The expected output is

| ID | date | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2012-04-30' | 5 |
| **1** | **'2012-05-31'** | **0** |
| 1 | '2012-06-30' | 4 |
| 1 | '2012-07-31' | 25 |
| 2 | '2012-04-30' | 7 |
| 2 | '2012-05-31' | 4 |
| 2 | '2012-06-30' | 1 |
| 2 | '2012-07-31' | 6 |

I need to add missing month and the date which gets added should be the last date of that

Comment: A calendar table is great for stuff like this. If you haven't invested in making one, yet, then now seems like an opportune time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest recursive CTEs:

```
with cte as (
      select id, date, frequency,
             lead(date) over (partition by id order by date) as next_date
      from t
      union all
      select id, eomonth(date, 1), 0, next_date
      from cte
      where eomonth(date, 1) < dateadd(day, -1, next_date)
     )
select id, date, frequency
from cte
order by id, date;
```

The anchor part of the CTE calculates the end date for a given row.  The recursive part then just keeps adding months to fill in the missing rows (and none if there are none).  The use of `eomonth(date, 1)` is just a handy way of getting the last day of the next month.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8733181f4ea837b5af227a80a8544cb6) is a db<>fiddle.

If you have all dates in the table, you can also use `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the existing data:

```
select i.id, d.date, coalesce(t.frequency, 0) as frequency
from (select distinct id from t) i cross join
     (select distinct date from t) d left join
     t
     on i.id = t.id and d.date = t.date
order by i.id, d.date;
```

If you have a large amount of data, you can compare performance.  This may be a case where a recursive CTE is faster than alternative methods.

Comment: Thanks for the queries Could you please give me brief on how the implementation of this is done using CTE.. Also one note The joins one is not so accurate as compared to the CTE,

Comment: select id, eomonth(date, 1), 0, next_date -> Are we doing this for the current row?